# How can I concisely check a webpage's resources for 404s using casperJS?

Tags: javascript, testing, http-status-code-404, phantomjs, casperjs

I have just started using Phantom/Casper.

So far I can list all the resources that a page has using this code:

```
casper.on('resource.received', function (resource) {
        casper.echo(resource.url);
   });
```

So far so good.

Now im trying to merge this with a chunk of code I gleaned and mashed from the documentation. I wanted to load each resource, and then print out the URL if it was missing:

```
casper.on('resource.received', function (resource) {
    //        casper.echo(resource.url);
    casper.Open(resource.url, function (resource) {
        this.on('http.status.404', function (resource) {
            this.echo('missing:' + resource.url);
        });
    });
});
```

It's messy, but it's what I've got. It fails to open the resources (ln 3), and the console shows no activity.

How can I rewrite this to iterate over the resources and check them for 404s?

(I am aware in my example that I'm not iterating over the resources, I was tempted to use eachthen(), but It's not clear if I can use general casperJS methods inside the 'test' prototype. Sorry, I hope this wasn't too long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS' `resource.received` is based on PhantomJS' [`onResourceReceived`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html). As you can see from the documentation, you can simply access `resource.status`. There is no need to explicitly load the resource.

```
casper.on('resource.received', function (resource) {
    if (resource.stage === "end" && resource.status === 404) {
        this.echo('missing:' + resource.url);
    };
});
```

Btw, you probably mean `casper.open` and not `casper.Open`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and succinct explanation. It worked perfectly!